# Android 5 Lollipop, android:scaleX, android:translationX, Y don't work in Android Studio layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio, scale, android-5.0-lollipop

I've many views (xml) in our project that contain android:translationX,Y and android:scaleX,Y for many kind of elements and I see in the Preview window of Android Studio (API-21) that they doesn't work.

A problem with the Preview window of Android Studio ?
I've not tried the preview for develper on our N5 and N7.
Do you have tested it ?
Do you have this problem in your Preview window too ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this only happen in Android 5 Lollipop? Or does it also happen when your app targets KitKat and below?

Comment: Hi, that happen only when I target API-21, all other (<21) work well.

Comment: I've just do the last update for the beta channel of Android Studio to take the 0.8.14. This is the same.

Comment: This sounds like a bug then. Inside Android Studio go to "Help --> Send Feedback" and you will be redirected to b.android.com where you can file a bug. Screenshots would probably help, as well as information about your gradle build file (targetSdkVersion, minSdkVersion, etc.).

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. I'll update this thread when it will be ok.

Comment: Hi, I confirm that is a bug in the IDE Beta. My issue on Code.google.com is categorized has "Labels: -Priority-Critical Priority-High ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that is a bug in the IDE Beta. My issue on Code.google.com is categorized has "Labels: -Priority-Critical Priority-High ". I'll update this thread when this will be resolved.

Comment: Hi, not for the moment, the issue was not updated and in the beta channel there is always the issue. Meanwhile, we can just switch to API 19 or less to do the design on the Peview window.